# What is the best practice regarding the use of the private keyword?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, private

In our React codebase I see `private` in front of almost every functions in all the components. This is a class component. eg:

```
private componentDidMount() {
   this.props.onLoad(false)
}

private UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(
   nextProps: Partial<IAdminPortalDispatchCarrierProps>,
)
```

What's the idea here? When would these methods be used publicly?

Comment: `private` is a Typescript visibility modifier for class members see: [private](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#private). Es6 classes implement native private members [Private class features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields) which are indicated using a hash `#` prefix.

Comment: `private componentDidMount` does not make any sense since it *will* be called from outside, by React, no matter what

Answer (score 0):

`private` is a [typescript modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#private), that makes these functions only accessible from inside the class. By marking something as private, typescript will give you a compile time error if you attempt to use the private function from outside the class. This lets you communicate to the other developers (including future-you) which pieces of code are meant for public consumption, and which ones are internal implementation details.

For the specific functions you listed though, I suggest making them public, not private. React [lifecycle hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class) must be called from outside the class to do their job. Specifically, they get called by react's internal code. Fortunately, typescript gets removed when compiling, so react is able to call your private functions regardless. But the misleading modifiers may lull you into a false sense that these functions are not being called.